# (Win10) Need help deleting permission protected steam game files/folders

Tags: windows-10, permissions

I don't know what else to do. Even running CMD as admin didn't work.
I've tried:

- Straight deleting, but it says I need Admin permissions to make changes
- Properties: Disable read-only, failed to disable
- Properties: changing permissions, failed to change
- Properties: changing ownership, didn't have option on inaccessibly folders
- `takeown /f "directory" /r`, but it keeps saying "Access is denied."
- `rd /s/q "directory"`, "Access is denied."
- `robocopy "C:\New folder" "directory" /MIR`, "Access is denied."

Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Did you try with takeown and icacls command?

Comment: I tried: takeown /f "foldername" /r. But, I got the response "INFO: Access is denied."

Comment: Download cygwin or you could also try the Ubuntu subsystem for Windows. All you'll have to do is use the rm -rf command and it'll wipe it away no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I managed.
The only way that didn't have any nagging errors was by going through safe mode.

http://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

Here I listed the commands:: Say, if your folder path is "C:\foo\bar"

`set X="C:\foo\bar"
takeown /F %X% /R /D Y
icacls %X% /grant Everyone:F /T
rd /S /Q %X%`

Try this commands with administrator privileged Command Prompt. No safe mode required.

Comment: Aside from 'set X="C:\foo\bar"', every step afterwards responds with "Access is denied.", and that is what I meant when I posted this. None of those commands worked, which may seem odd, but they legitimately do not work in any way for me.